# animate two elements side-by-side doesn't work (fadeIn, fadeout, animate)

Tags: jquery

I am trying to animate two elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/1tLfwrhg/

```
font {
  display: block;
}

.red {
  font-size: 150%;
  color: red;
}

<font id="test1" size="7">0000000000000000</font>
<font id="test2" size="7">0000000000000000</font>

$('#test1, #test2').fadeOut(500, function() {
  $('#test1, #test2').text('11111111111111111111')
  $('#test1, #test2').fadeIn(500)
  $('#test1, #test2').fadeOut(500, () => {
    $('#test1, #test2').text('2222222222222222');
    $('#test1, #test2').css("color", "green").addClass("red")
  })
  $('#test1, #test2').fadeIn(500)
  $('#test1, #test2').delay(500)
  $("#test1").animate({
    'margin-left': '150px'
  }, {
    duration: 100
  })
  $("#test2").animate({
    'margin-left': '300px'
  }, {
    duration: 1000
  })
  $('#test1, #test2').delay(1000)
  $('#test1, #test2').fadeOut(500)
});
```

At the beginning the animation looks fine. But at the end I get a strange blinking and I don't know why...

Comment: It's because the `duration`s are different, what were you hoping for instead?

Comment: well, at the end there should be one fadeOut(500) for both elements. But there is some sort of blinking, multiple times fadeIn and fadeOut.

Comment: Do you want `test2`'s animation to finish (takes 900ms longer than `test1`'s), then delay 1000ms, then have both elements fade out together over 500ms?

Comment: Yes, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can chain together all the `fade` and `delay` calls that are identical for each element. Put the `.text()` calls inside the `fade` callback, eg:

```
const $tests = $('#test1, #test2');
$tests
  .fadeOut(500, () => {
    $tests.text('11111111111111111111')
  })
  .fadeIn(500)
```

Then, once the actions for the two elements *diverge*, call `.animate` on both elements separately, and then use `.promise()` on *both* to wait until all animations for all elements in the collection are completely done:

```
$("#test1").animate({
  'margin-left': '150px'
}, {
  duration: 100
})
$("#test2").animate({
  'margin-left': '300px'
}, {
  duration: 1000
});
$tests
  .promise()
  .done(() => {
    // all animations are done
```

In full:

```js
const $tests = $('#test1, #test2');
$tests
  .fadeOut(500, () => {
    $tests.text('11111111111111111111')
  })
  .fadeIn(500)
  .fadeOut(500, () => {
    $('#test1, #test2').text('2222222222222222');
    $('#test1, #test2').css("color", "green").addClass("red")
  })
  .fadeIn(500)
  .delay(500);
$("#test1").animate({
  'margin-left': '150px'
}, {
  duration: 100
})
$("#test2").animate({
  'margin-left': '300px'
}, {
  duration: 1000
});
$tests
  .promise()
  .done(() => {
    $tests
      .delay(100)
      .fadeOut(500)
  })
```

```css
font {
  display: block;
}

.red {
  font-size: 150%;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<font id="test1" size="7">0000000000000000</font>
<font id="test2" size="7">0000000000000000</font>
```